# Perguntas sobre tradução de termo técnico

Tags: suporte

O site [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) pode ser usado para fazer perguntas sobre tradução de termos técnicos?

Por exemplo, eu gostaria de obter uma boa tradução para a expressão `flush the standard output` comumente encontrada na descrição de operações de entrada e saída oferecidas por linguagens de programação.

Answer (score 6):

Eu acredito que sim, mas só postando a pergunta e vendo a reação da comunidade para ter certeza. Temos inclusive uma tag [terminologia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminologia) que poderia ser utilizada. A pergunta mais parecida que encontrei no site foi *[Como ler/traduzir a palavra-chave yield?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53547/como-ler-traduzir-a-palavra-chave-yield)*.

Comment: Eu também havia encontrado esta pergunta que você mencionou. Porém fiquei receoso de não ser bem vinda, uma vez que nos comentários alguém sugere não ser apropriado.

Comment: Ela está numa "zona cizenta". Por isso que eu disse, só postando e vendo como as pessoas reagem.

Comment: Postei minha perguntada [Tradução da palavra flush](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58432/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-palavra-flush). Aguardando a reação dos membros.

Comment: Ao meu ver, seria uma pergunta válida se você marcar nas tags onde o termo é usado, porque pode ser que C++ isso seja uma coisa e no java isso seja outra coisa, jogar ela como tradução sem focar onde específicamente é a dúvida/problema, me deixa pensar que aqui não seria o melhor lugar para expor, no mais é uma pergunta dentro do contexto da programação, então válida.

Comment: @Romildo Reação dos membros: "Pergunta legal" :)

Comment: Parece que a comunidade reage bem a traduções ligadas a programação :)